# NSInternalInconsistencyException in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I am having a crash in firebase. I have attached a screen shot below. please have a look.
Any support will be highly appreciated.

I Tried some do-try-catch method. But i think that firebase api is not throwing any error. it is not useful.

We had a lot of crash recently with the following error:
FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Failed to commit transaction: <LevelDbTransaction NextMutationBatchAfterBatchID: 0 changes (0 bytes):> Failed: IO error: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1D9183C6-D12F-42CB-8A18-A408B7F5F841/Library/Application Support/firestore/__FIRAPP_DEFAULT/[APP-NAME]/main/001236.ldb: No space left on device (expected status.ok())

Comment: It looks like the users phone has no storage space available

Comment: That's right, but is there any way to stop the crashes in our app or not.

Comment: @Dafurman Hii can you please help me out in this crash

Answer (score 1):

It seems the error message is due to rough edges of Firestore internals.

Below are the troubleshooting steps which you can try:

1. Monitor free space on the device and disable persistence if free space drops below a certain threshold.In order to disable persistence, you would need to shut down the FIRFirestore instance by calling its terminate method. You could even free up a bit of disk space by calling clearPersistence. Then, you can restart the FIRFirestore instance with a FIRFirestoreSettings object with its persistenceEnabled property set to false.
2. Limit the cache size. This value can be specified in the FIRFirestoreSettings cacheSizeBytes property.

You can also refer to this github [link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/10168) for more information.